# My Canadaian university denied my religious vaccine exemption request, what type of lawyer do I speak to?

Tags: canada, covid-19, school, vaccination

I am situated in Canada. And go to a Canadian university (in Toronto). My university has a vaccine mandate for the Covid-19 vaccine, which I have requested an exemption to, due to issues with the vaccine and my religion.

Anyways, I would like to know more about why I was denied and how I can remediate this, and think that speaking to a lawyer about this (my response to the denial) is my best move. So, since im not from Canada (from US), I dont know what type of lawyer to try and contact...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Canadian lawyers who handle this kind of matter usually describe themselves as "human rights" and/or "discrimination" lawyers.

No formal regulatory specialty is recognized or required, however. Any licensed lawyer in good standing is legally permitted to take on such a case.